# Full Page <iframe>

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have the example code below. This works fine with all browsers except for browsers on mobile devices.

The overflow tag is the issue.

Works with all except for mobile:

```
margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
```

Works with all mobile and not computers:

```
margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%;
```

**What's the best way to get it to work on both?**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test Layout</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html
            {
                margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.cnn.com" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just redirect to `cnn.com`?

Comment: cnn.com is more of an example. to show the behavior that i'm trying to prevent.

Comment: just add 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> ` 
to the head of the containing html and responsiveness is back again (at least partially).

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Here's the working code. It works in desktop and mobile browsers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test Layout</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html
            {
                margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
            }

            #content
            {
                position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="http://cnn.com"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: watch out, when I wanted to put an iframe over above - there was a problem in Chrome. I added closing </iframe> and works

Comment: Seems like it's taking away the _responsiveness_ (i.e. collapsing of columns, etc) from the content within the iframe. But somehow only when opening the page with mobile safari, not when resizing a desktop browser. Any ideas what could cause that behaviour?

Comment: @psteinweber, you just need to add `<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>` to the containing page.

Comment: Had to use `vw` instead of `%` for `width` and `height ` properties to get proper alignment in Chromium 81. Otherwise works like a charm.

Comment: for me it aslo worked without setting #content part. thanks

Answer (score 54):

This is cross-browser and fully responsive:

```
<iframe
  src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxrMaW3xINrsR3h2cWx0OUlwRms/preview"
  style="
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 999999;
    height: 100%;
  ">
</iframe>
```

Comment: This looks neat and works better than the accepted solution.

Answer (score 11):

Put this in your CSS.

```
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I have used in the past.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Also in the `iframe` add the following style

```
border: 0; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but it's essentially what I have so it doesn't work.  On the mobile browser it cuts off any thing that is overflow and doesn't let you scroll.

Comment: @Lacer Try replacing `overflow: hidden` with `overflow: auto`

Comment: did try that. on mobile browser it still cuts it off and on the desktop browsers it causes double scrolls

Comment: nope still the double scroll in desktop browser and cuts off on mobile browsers

Answer (score 4):

For full-screen frame redirects and similar things I have two methods. Both work fine on mobile and desktop.

Note this are complete cross-browser working, valid HTML files. Just change `title` and `src` for your needs.

**1. this** is my favorite:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title> Title-1 </title>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width">
<style>
 html, body, iframe { height:100%; width:100%; margin:0; border:0; display:block }
</style>
<iframe src=src1></iframe>

<!-- More verbose CSS for better understanding:
  html   { height:100% }
  body   { height:100%; margin:0 }
  iframe { height:100%; width:100%; border:0; display:block }
-->
```

**or 2. something like that**, slightly shorter:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title> Title-2 </title>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width">
<iframe src=src2 style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:0">
</iframe>
```

**Note**: 
The above examples avoid using `height:100vh` because old browsers don't know it (maybe moot these days) and `height:100vh` is not always equal to `height:100%` on mobile browsers (probably not applicable here). Otherwise, `vh` simplifies things a little bit, so

**3. this is an example using vh** (not my favorite, less compatible with little advantage)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title> Title-3 </title>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width">
<style>
 body { margin:0 }
 iframe { display:block; width:100%; height:100vh; border:0 }
</style>
<iframe src=src3></iframe>
```

Answer (score -2):

Set the iframe to height 100vh and width 100%:

```html
<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com" 
    style="
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 999999;
      height: 100%;
  ">
</iframe>
```