# How can I hide a link of other website linked on my website in native php

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have button book flights.

```html
<a class="book-flight-btn" href="https://fairdealtravel.tripprosites.com/">Book flight</a>
```

and it will take user to a flight booking website.
I don't want to show this link "https://fairdealtravel.tripprosites.com/" in the url bar. the link in the url bar should be like this/ "https://mydomainame.com/flight". I am working in native Php and jquery.

Comment: You could maybe use an iframe?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374696/htaccess-url-redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I would do if I were you:

The following would be https://mydomainame.com/flight.php or flight depending on your htaccess.

You a button would now be:

```
<a class="book-flight-btn" href="https://mydomainame.com/flight>Book flight</a>
```

in flight.php You would have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test Layout</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html
            {
                margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
            }

            #content
            {
                position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="https://fairdealtravel.tripprosites.com/" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The previous html code is what is recommended by this question: [Full Page <iframe>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710039/full-page-iframe)

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide the URL, if the browser on the URL. But you can use `<iframe>` tag.
Put the following code in a file, to which you set the URL `https://mydomainame.com/flight`:

```
<body style="margin: 0; max-width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden;">
    <iframe src="https://fairdealtravel.tripprosites.com/" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
</body>
```

Note that you have to put this link `https://mydomainame.com/flight` to your button `href`:

```
<a class="book-flight-btn" href="https://mydomainame.com/flight">Book flight</a>
```